# EasyMock use method

Tags: easymock

I am trying to run just a simple test using easyMock:

```
public class Class1 implements Interface1{
    public void method1(Object obj){
       if(isEnable()){
    doSmth();
    }
    }

    public boolean isEnable(){
    return isEnable;
    }
}
```

My test:

```
Interface1 test1= Interface1(Class1.class);
test1.method1(anyObject);
expectLastCall();
expect(test1.isEnable).andReturn(true);
replay(test1);

test1.method1(new Object());
verify(test1);
```

Error:

> Expectation failure on verify:
>       isEnable(): expected: 1, actual: 0

Where is the problem? I have read tons of examples where there are similar problems with the parameters sent, but not a method without params [example1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-easymock/index.html) or this [tutorial](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/06/20/getting-started-with-easymock-2.html), that I found interesting

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change the mocking code little bit. You are wanting to call a method **isEnable** and return true.

```
Interface1 test1= Interface1(Class1.class);
test1.method1(anyObject);
expectLastCall();
expect(test1.isEnable()).andReturn(true);
replay(test1);
```

Change you actual test to

```
test1.method1(new Object());
test1.isEnable();
verify(test1);
```